# Не запускается тест mocha/chai

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, npm, mocha, chai

Перерыл много статей в интернете и посмотрел несколько видео про `Mocha | Chai`, после пробы всех вариантов, так и не получилось запустить даже первый тест.

При запуске `npm run test` выбивает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка и **package.json** \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/

Cсылка на github проект - https://github.com/ZakharovVladyslav/JavaScript/tree/main/Testing

Структура директории:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`app.js:`

```js
'use strict'

class NewClass {
    constructor() {
        console.log("initiate")
    }

    add(arg1, arg2) {
        var result
        result = arg1 + arg2
        return result
    }
}

export default NewClass
```

`test.spec.js:`

```js
import NewClass from "../app/app.js"
let newObj = new NewClass()
import { expect as _expect } from "chai"
let expect = chai._expect

describe("Test suit", function() {
    it("Test the add method", function() {
        expect(newObj.add(1, 2)).to.be.equal(3)
    })
})
```

`package.json:`

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "test.spec.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "mocha": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

`Terminal output:`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выложите свой проект на github или на repl.it

Comment: Вопрос обновил, ссылку добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ./**/*spec.js"
  }
```

Почему у вас package.json в папке test? должен быть в корневой папке проекта!

когда куда-то проект заливаете - папку package.json добавлять не нужно.
добавьте ее в gitignore, поищите как

Comment: папку node_modules добавлять не нужно***